# ASP.NET Health Monitoring configuration, valid values for the "eventName" attribute

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

What are the valid values for the eventName attribute when configuring Health Monitoring?

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="0">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="exampleMailWebEventProvider"
      type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider"
      to="email@example.com"
      from="error@example.com"
      buffer="false"
      subjectPrefix="[Exception] " />
  </providers>

  <rules>
    <add
      name="Testing Mail Event Providers"
      eventName="All Events"
      provider="exampleMailWebEventProvider"
      profile="Default"
      minInstances="1"
      maxLimit="Infinite"
      minInterval="00:01:00"
      custom="" />
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

My Google-fu (and MSDN) has failed me, and I can't find a list of all the other default/common events you can subscribe to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

... aaaaaand here we go: [MSDN, eventMappings Element for healthMonitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc5yk01w.aspx)
(amazing how far a little extra effort and patience can get you)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the web.config in your %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\CONFIG folder